# Chrome does not support adding searchEngine through javascript 'window.external.AddSearchProvider(url)'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opensearchdescription

I am here to clarify an issue am facing in chrome alone and the issue is - 'I can't able to add My Site in chrome search engine via Javascript **`window.external.AddSearchProvider(xml_url)`** , However,on earlier times,  it worked properly without any issues.'

I am not doing auto-adding my site to search engine with help of '`<link>`' tag (however, this too does not worked for me)

The  '`window.external.AddSearchProvider(xml_url)`  works fine in firefox as earlier,,, The problem is only with the chrome, since, chrome supported earlier, and don't know the root cause of not able to add now. Please help me to figure out the issue by which i cant able to add in chrome Search Engine.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `window.external.AddSearchProvider` is obsolete. It is working in Firefox but is no longer supported.

The `<link>` tag that you add in your site's `<head>` is for *Autodiscovery of search plugins* feature, this will list your site search engine in the configurations of the browser.

In chrome will list at `chrome://settings/searchEngines`

Comment: Thanks for your Heads up @Conrado

Comment: I tried this approach. I am facing trouble with this inline tag concept. What I exactly tried was:
- On button click, create `<link>`,  with JQuery, attach XML file URL, title and appending to `<head>` tag.

Please let me know whether i am missing any stuff on this.

Also, looked into my search engine lists, got to know there is some other sites 'search engine' was added. So I deleted it, I visited that site again. And came back to my search engine list page. Now that search engine provider does not exist. However, that website has, this `<link'> with its XML.